# Term for "maybe" when answering a question in conversation

Tags: spoken-language

If someone asks you a question, for example:

> 明日、一緒に行く？

What is a natural way to say "maybe"?

I am familiar with various ways to express uncertainty:

> 多分
>   だろう
>   かもしれない

However I think none of these may sound too natural, or at least express the same light(?) feeling of English "maybe".

The best I can think of is:

> うん〜考えとく。

Is there anything else that would fit here to express uncertainty?

> 行くかもしれない

Sounds stiff to me.

> さぁ〜

Sounds too rude.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly address the word "maybe", but a very Japanese answer would be

> まー、行けたら行く。　→　I'll go if I'm able.

Like "maybe", this gives the impression that you more than likely won't be able to go.  Also note that most of the time, to a Japanese person this is just a polite, indirect way of saying "no"; the same way 難しい usually means "no" and not actually "it will be difficult".

Comment: Interesting, hadn't seen that one. By the way, I think different people may have different ideas about "maybe" in English. For example, I thought it was closer to a 50/50 chance, though it depends on their tone of voice.

Comment: Is the above expression commonly said just like that? I feel that maybe "行けたら、行くけど。。。”　might be more common.

Comment: They might be with a "softener" like `まぁ`.  Edited answer.